# The in-app-browser@5.0.0 detect 'beforeload' events just sometimes

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-native, inappbrowser

I'm trying to implement a mobile application for Android and iOS using Ionic (it's my first time with mobile apps) that uses in-app-browser to access a portal. The point is that portal sends signals to the app through redirections that I intercept to perform a specific action (the interception is done with 'beforeload' events and prevents the redirection). **The issue is that on Android, these redirections are only detected 'sometimes,' intermittently, while on iOS, it works perfectly**. If anyone could lend me a hand, thank you!

The expected outcome is precisely to detect all redirections before they are executed and be able to handle them conditionally **"beforehand"**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.